How to change folder to another Git repo?
I created a folder containing some code. I sent it to a github repo I created in the past (let's say I nammed it "Folder v1"). Now, I would like to work on a new repo I just created nammed "Folder v2".
So I would like to "send" my folder to this new repo and work from this repo and commit/push automaticaly to this new repo.
PS : I can use VScode if it's easier.
Thank you

You'd have to add the new repo as a remote (and then remove the old remote if not needed any more). Take a look at the doc. An alternative is to just change your remote's url through git remote set-url

You can change a remote repo with git remote set-url origin <url for new repo> and you should be able to commit/push as usual.
Or you can work on both repos by adding second remote with
git remote add folder2 <url for repo>
And push to it with
git push folder2 <branch_name>
